# Kendo UI Uploader inside Kendo List View

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-upload, kendo-listview

Is it possible to add kendo uploader inside kendo ListView?

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="templateMessage">
    <div class="Row" style="padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px !important;">
        <div style="width: 15%; float: @_Layout.Align; padding-left: 2px;" class="gridText">
            #:CheckList#     
        </div>
        <div style="width: 50%; float: @_Layout.Align; padding-left: 2px;" class="gridText">
            @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
                .Name("file")
                .Async(a => a
                    .Save("SavePic", "Home")
                    .Remove("RemovePic", "Home")
                    .AutoUpload(true))
                .Multiple(false)            
            )
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few points that you need to cover:

1. all the ToClientTemplate extensions when you position widget inside
   a client template.
2. escape the sharp symbols if you have used any inside your widget declaration:

   function(e) {
   e.data = { id: $("\#Id").val() };
   }

Answer (score 2):

I think it's possible. Just have to always remember calling the `ToClientTemplate()` method when using kendo widgets in a client template.

In this case:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
            .Name("file")
            .Async(a => a
                .Save("SavePic", "Home")
                .Remove("RemovePic", "Home")
                .AutoUpload(true))
            .Multiple(false)            
            .toClientTemplate()
        )
```

**UPDATED:**
You may escape use "#" in JavaScript strings using `"\\#"` and in HTML script templates using `"\#"`.